# Possible sprockets-rails gem issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, sprockets

I've just created a new Vagrant box to be able to develop my Rails app. The box is brand new and has Ruby, MySQL etc installed to be able to develop.

I've installed all gems etc but when I try to start the app I get the following:

```
vagrant@neiltongesite:/vagrant/source$ bundle exec foreman start
17:45:02 rails.1 | started with pid 5910
17:45:05 rails.1 | /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:108:in `block in <class:Railtie>': undefined method `+' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.7/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.7/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.7/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.7/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.7/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.7/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.7/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.7/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.7/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /vagrant/source/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /vagrant/source/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /vagrant/source/config.ru:in `new'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /vagrant/source/config.ru:in `<main>'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/2.2.7/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from bin/rails:4:in `require'
17:45:05 rails.1 |  from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
17:45:05 rails.1 | => Booting Puma
17:45:05 rails.1 | => Rails 4.2.5.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
17:45:05 rails.1 | => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
17:45:05 rails.1 | => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
17:45:05 rails.1 | Exiting
17:45:05 rails.1 | exited with code 1
17:45:05 system  | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

I've looked but can't seem to figure out what is causing it.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: What's here `/vagrant/source/config/environment.rb:5`?

Comment: @Uzbekjon That line is: MyAppName::Application.initialize!

Comment: @Uzbekjon Any more thoughts on this? It's annoying me so much.

Comment: any chance that you can provide something that is easily reproducable - github project ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Unfortunately I can't provide a link as it's all local and for certain reasons, I can't link to the repo. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is thrown on [this line](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/v3.2.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb#L108), so I guess you have the following somewhere in your configuration files:

```
config.assets.precompile = false
```

This configuration setting should define **an array of assets that you want to be precompiled**, it should not be set to `false`. See the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) for more info.

To test this hypothesis I configured a test Rails 5 project with the above line and got the same exception:

```
.../gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:108:in `block in <class:Railtie>': undefined method `+' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thankyou. Please can you tell me how you located that the issue was caused by that line?

Comment: It's in the first line of the stack trace that you put into the question. It says `.../sprocket-rails-3.2.0/.../railtie: 108`. So I googled the sprocket rails gem source and found the line. From there, the issue was quite apparent.